# Integer overflow in memory allocation error on ec2 server

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2

I am working on Lumen microservice and I have run query in laravel lumen and received following error

```
> Fatal error: Possible integer overflow in memory allocation (3626020824 * 32 + 32)
 in /var/app/current/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php on line 188
```

my code is deployed on AWS ec2 beanstalk server.

Answer (score 0):

int minimum value is -2147483648 and maximum value 2147483647, try BIGINT, or varchar